# Why the count of i is not increased even after calling run() 2 times?

Tags: java, multithreading

Why the count of i is not increased even after calling run() 2 times?

```
public class Test extends Thread{
  private int i;//default value is 0

  public void run(){
        i++;//increas value of i by 1

  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
        Test a = new Test();
        System.out.println(a.i); // prints 0
        a.run();//direct call
        System.out.println(a.i);// prints 1
        a.start();// calls run()
        System.out.println(a.i );// again prints 1
  }
}
```

Comment: @Tacolibre `Test extends Thread`

Comment: You only call `run()` once.

Comment: Maybe the last `println` is happening before the thread has started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to to wait for the thread to finish before processing the final result you need to use the `join` method.

Catch or throw the respective exception. I simply threw it in this case.

```
public class Test extends Thread{
  private int i;//default value is 0

  public void run(){
        i++;//increas value of i by 1

  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Test a = new Test();
        System.out.println(a.i); // prints 0
        a.run();//direct call
        System.out.println(a.i);// prints 1
        a.start();// calls run()

        a.join(); //Wait for the thread to finish

        System.out.println(a.i );// again prints 2
  }
}
```

Comment: got it. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: worth to mention that executing run on a Thread is not the way it is meant to be used. Also, an alternative to join is to use concurrent utilities as a CountDownLatch, which also provides other features as configuring a max time waiting, instead of forever.

Answer (score 4):

You only call `run()` once.

When you call `start()`, it start another thread which runs later, at some time. In this case, long after your `main` has finished most likely.

Starting a thread is neither synchronous, nor instantaneous, otherwise there would be no point using one.

Answer (score 0):

You run two thread separatly the first one is quick than the second for that when the first thread finished it print 1, then start the thread 2 just after that you make a print for that you see two time `1`, to understand more you can make a sleep like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Test a = new Test();
    System.out.println(a.i);
    a.run();//direct call
    System.out.println(a.i);
    a.start();// calls run()
    Thread.sleep(1000);//<<----------------------------------Sleep a while
    System.out.println(a.i);
}
```

In this case you will see :

```
0
1
2
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call "start" the thread is started in the background. This call is async by definition. So you cannot grant (they way you have coded it) that the last print will be executed after the run method on the thread finishes. That's the point with threads.

If you execute run directly, you are not making use of the thread, that's not async. You're just executing the method implementation directly. Threads are not meant to be used this way.

Answer (score 0):

`a.run()` is a blocking call.
It returns only when `run()` has terminated its execution.
So you are bound to see `i` be incremented.

`a.start()` will call `run()` but may return before `run()` is returned.
So you are not bound to see `i` be incremented.

Comment: It's sort of strange to use the word "blocking" when you are talking about a method call.

Answer (score 0):

> Why the count of i is not increased even after calling run() 2 times?

As mentioned by others, the main problem is that if the currently running thread calls the `run()` method directly, `i` will get immediately updated.  If you call `start()` there is nothing that guarantees that the background thread will call `run()` before the `System.out.println(...)` line is reached.

It is also important to realize that even if the thread *does* call the `run()` method, there is nothing that ensures that the main thread will actually see the updated value for `i`.  Not only does `a.join();` wait for the background thread to finish but it also ensures that any memory changes made by that thread are seen by the main thread.

Any data that is shared between threads needs to be marked `volatile` or otherwise synchronized to ensure proper sharing and visibility of changes.

```
Test a = new Test();
System.out.println(a.i); // prints 0
a.run(); //direct call, i updated in this thread
System.out.println(a.i); // prints 1
a.start(); // starts the process of creating a new thread, run() called in the future
a.join();  // ensure that the background thread calls run() _and_ value of i is updated
System.out.println(a.i ); // now prints 2
```